# Dell XPS 9395: Disable pgup/pgdwn keys

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I have a new Dell 0395 notebook. I am accidentally pressing the pgup/pgdown keys very often intending to use left/right arrow-keys.

It might  be a matter of time to get used to it but I am writing on a paper atm and just want to disable the keys (ie assigning left/right to them).

I am using ubuntu 17.04 (gnome) and are not able to fit the examples how to modify a keyboard-layout to my system. Are there easy ways to disable the keys or assign new values to it?

Comment: ok but why are you down-rating the answer?.. It might had been a comment rather than an answer.. but I saw similar answers not down-rated.. so..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys) is a question similar to yours. You can follow the steps from the answer.